# How to solve the server start's deprecation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In rails 5, I am getting the below error while starting the server.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)
```

I have tried to fix it by updating the devise gem like `gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'` and `gem "devise", '~> 4.0.0.rc1'` and only `gem 'devise'` but there is no use.

Gemfile is,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a     debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
 gem 'web-console'
 gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

## ------- Referred from Pinhopes --------------------

gem 'httpclient'

gem 'psych'

gem 'less-rails'

gem "asset_sync"

gem 'rubyzip'

gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"

gem 'fb_graph'

gem 'twitter'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'twitter_oauth'

gem 'sunspot_rails'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end

gem 'progress_bar'

# for shortening the Long URL before posting to twitter
gem 'bitly'

gem 'paperclip'

gem 'posix-spawn'

gem "aws-sdk"

gem "cocaine"

gem 'execjs'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'

## Used to avoid => DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method  `register_engine` is deprecated. & Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`
gem 'sprockets', '3.6.3'

gem 'colorize'

gem "responds_to_parent"

gem "simple_form"

gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'

gem 'cloudfront-signer'

gem 'docsplit'

gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

gem 'geocoder'

gem 'money'

gem 'google_currency'

gem 'reporter', '0.0.14.alpha' , :git => "https://github.com/kpvarma/reporter.git"

gem 'oa-core'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem "omniauth-linkedin-oauth2"

gem "nokogiri"

gem 'dalli'

gem 'stripe'

gem 'unicorn'

gem 'grape'

gem 'grape-swagger'

gem 'roo'

gem 'remotipart'

gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'

gem 'protected_attributes_continued'

gem "spreadsheet", "0.9.0"

# ------- For Code Optimization & CleanUp ---------
group :development do
  gem 'traceroute'

  #gem 'rack-mini-profiler'

  gem 'bullet'

  gem 'brakeman', require: false

  gem 'rails_best_practices'

  gem 'rubocop', require: false

  gem 'rubycritic', require: false
end

## Deadweight is used for cleaning unused CSS selectors.
group :test do
  gem 'colored'
  gem 'deadweight', require: 'deadweight/hijack/rails'
end
#----------------------------------------------------------
```

Gem lists are like,

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract_type (0.0.7)
actioncable (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0)
actionmailer (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
actionpack (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
actionview (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0)
activejob (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0)
activemodel (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
activerecord (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
activesupport (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
adamantium (0.2.0)
addressable (2.4.0, 2.3.8)
andand (1.3.3)
arel (7.1.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.0, 4.0.2)
asset_sync (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0)
ast (2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0)
astrolabe (1.3.1)
attr_required (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
aws-sdk (2.6.1, 2.5.3, 2.2.16, 1.66.0, 1.64.0, 1.51.0)
aws-sdk-core (2.6.1, 2.5.3, 2.2.16)
aws-sdk-resources (2.6.1, 2.5.3, 2.2.16)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.66.0, 1.64.0)
aws-ses (0.6.0)
axiom-types (0.1.1)
bcrypt (3.1.11, 3.1.10, 3.1.7)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bitly (0.10.4)
bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (4.7.14)
brakeman (3.4.0, 3.1.5, 3.1.1)
buftok (0.2.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4)
bullet (5.4.0, 5.0.0, 4.14.9)
bundler (1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
byebug (9.0.5, 8.2.2, 6.0.2)
CFPropertyList (2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.3.1)
chronic (0.10.2)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cloudfront-signer (3.0.0)
cocaine (0.5.8, 0.5.7, 0.5.3)
code_analyzer (0.4.7, 0.4.5)
codeclimate-engine-rb (0.3.1)
coercible (1.0.0)
coffee-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1, 2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0, 1.9.1.1, 1.7.0)
colored (1.2)
colorize (0.8.1, 0.7.7, 0.7.3, 0.5.8)
commonjs (0.2.7)
concord (0.1.5)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
config (1.0.0)
connection_pool (2.2.0)
css_parser (1.2.6)
daemons (1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2)
dalli (2.7.6, 2.7.4)
deadweight (0.2.2)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
deep_merge (1.0.1)
delayed_job (4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.0.6)
delayed_job_active_record (4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.3)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
devise (4.2.0, 4.0.3, 3.5.6, 3.5.2, 3.5.1, 3.2.4)
devise_token_auth (0.1.39)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
docsplit (0.7.6, 0.7.2)
domain_name (0.5.20160826, 0.5.25)
encryptor (3.0.0)
enumerable-lazy (0.0.1)
equalizer (0.0.11, 0.0.10)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.8, 1.0.7)
excel2csv (0.3.4)
excon (0.52.0, 0.45.4, 0.45.3)
execjs (2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.2.0, 1.2.6)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
faraday (0.9.2, 0.9.1)
faraday_middleware (0.10.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fb_graph (2.7.17)
ffi (1.9.14, 1.9.10, 1.9.3)
fission (0.5.0)
flay (2.8.1, 2.8.0, 2.6.1, 2.4.0)
flog (4.4.0, 4.3.2, 4.2.1)
flowplayer-rails (0.0.3)
fog (1.38.0, 1.34.0, 1.31.0)
fog-aliyun (0.1.0)
fog-atmos (0.1.0)
fog-aws (0.11.0, 0.7.6, 0.4.0)
fog-brightbox (0.11.0, 0.9.0, 0.7.1)
fog-cloudatcost (0.1.2)
fog-core (1.42.0, 1.32.1, 1.30.0)
fog-dynect (0.0.3, 0.0.2)
fog-ecloud (0.3.0, 0.1.2)
fog-google (0.1.1, 0.1.0, 0.0.5)
fog-json (1.0.2)
fog-local (0.3.0, 0.2.1)
fog-openstack (0.1.12)
fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
fog-profitbricks (2.0.1, 0.0.5, 0.0.3)
fog-rackspace (0.1.1)
fog-radosgw (0.0.5, 0.0.4)
fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
fog-sakuracloud (1.7.5, 1.3.3, 1.0.1)
fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
fog-softlayer (1.1.4, 0.4.7, 0.4.6)
fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
fog-terremark (0.1.0)
fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
fog-voxel (0.1.0)
fog-vsphere (1.1.0, 1.0.1)
fog-xenserver (0.2.3)
fog-xml (0.1.2)
formatador (0.2.5)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
geocoder (1.4.0, 1.2.11, 1.2.8)
geokit (1.10.0)
geokit-rails (2.1.0)
globalid (0.3.7, 0.3.6, 0.3.5)
google_currency (3.3.0, 3.2.0)
google_timezone (0.0.5)
grape (0.17.0, 0.13.0, 0.11.0)
grape-entity (0.5.1, 0.4.8, 0.4.5)
grape-swagger (0.23.0, 0.10.2, 0.7.2)
haml (4.0.7)
hashie (3.4.6, 3.4.4, 3.4.2)
highline (1.7.8, 1.7.7, 1.6.21)
hike (1.2.3)
http (1.0.4, 0.9.8, 0.6.4)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
http-form_data (1.0.1)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
httparty (0.14.0, 0.13.7, 0.13.5)
httpclient (2.8.2.4, 2.5.3.3)
i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.9)
ice_nine (0.11.2, 0.11.1)
inflecto (0.0.2)
inline_svg (0.6.2)
io-console (0.4.3)
ipaddress (0.8.3, 0.8.0)
jbuilder (2.6.0, 2.4.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 1.5.3)
jmespath (1.3.1, 1.1.3)
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.6, 0.4.5, 0.4.1)
jquery-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
jwt (1.5.6, 1.5.5, 1.5.4, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0)
kdtree (0.3)
kgio (2.10.0, 2.9.3)
kramdown (1.12.0, 1.9.0, 1.7.0)
kristin (0.4.1)
launchy (2.4.3)
less (2.6.0)
less-rails (2.7.1, 2.7.0)
libv8 (3.16.14.15 x86_64-linux, 3.16.14.13 x86_64-linux, 3.16.14.11  x86_64-linux, 3.16.14.7 x86_64-linux)
listen (3.0.8)
loofah (2.0.3, 2.0.2)
mail (2.6.4, 2.6.3, 2.5.4)
memoizable (0.4.2)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1, 3.0, 2.99, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 1.25.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521, 3.2016.0221)
mimemagic (0.3.2, 0.3.0)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
minitest (5.9.0, 5.8.4, 5.8.2, 5.8.1, 5.8.0, 5.7.0, 4.7.5)
momentjs-rails (2.10.3)
money (6.7.1, 6.5.1)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.0, 1.10.1)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mustermann19 (0.4.4)
mysql2 (0.4.4, 0.4.3, 0.4.2, 0.3.20, 0.3.18)
naught (1.1.0, 1.0.0)
nearest_time_zone (0.0.4)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (3.0.1, 2.9.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
netrc (0.11.0)
nio4r (1.2.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8, 1.6.7.2, 1.6.6.2)
noti (1.0.2)
notifyor (0.8.1)
oa-core (0.3.2)
oauth (0.5.1, 0.4.7)
oauth2 (1.2.0, 1.0.0)
omniauth (1.3.1, 1.2.2)
omniauth-facebook (4.0.0, 2.0.1)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.4.1, 0.2.8, 0.2.6)
omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 (0.1.5)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.0)
omniauth-stripe-connect (2.9.0)
options (2.3.2)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperclip (5.1.0, 4.3.5, 4.2.2)
parse-ruby-client (0.3.0)
parser (2.3.1.2, 2.3.0.6, 2.2.3.0)
path_expander (1.0.0)
pdf2html (0.1.0)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
polyglot (0.3.5)
posix-spawn (0.3.11)
powerpack (0.1.1)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
private_attr (1.1.0)
procto (0.0.2)
progress_bar (1.0.5, 1.0.3)
protected_attributes (1.1.3, 1.0.9)
protected_attributes_continued (1.2.2)
psych (2.1.1, 2.0.15, 2.0.13, 2.0.8)
puma (3.6.0)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.4, 1.6.1, 1.5.5, 1.5.2)
rack-accept (0.4.5)
rack-mini-profiler (0.9.7)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-oauth2 (1.4.0, 1.2.1, 1.1.1)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
rails (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.1, 1.0.7, 1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3, 1.0.2)
rails_best_practices (1.17.0, 1.15.7)
rails_config (0.99.0)
railties (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 4.0.2)
rainbow (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
raindrops (0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.15.0, 0.13.0)
rake (11.2.2, 11.1.2, 10.5.0, 10.4.2, 10.3.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rbvmomi (1.8.2)
rdoc (4.2.2, 4.2.0)
redis (3.3.0)
reek (4.4.1, 4.1.0, 3.10.1, 1.6.5)
ref (2.0.0, 1.0.5)
remotipart (1.3.0, 1.2.1)
require_all (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
responders (2.3.0, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 1.1.2)
responds_to_parent (1.1.0)
rest-client (2.0.0, 1.8.0)
roo (2.5.1, 2.3.1, 1.13.2)
rsolr (1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.0.13, 1.0.12)
rubocop (0.43.0, 0.42.0, 0.37.2, 0.34.2)
ruby-ole (1.2.12, 1.2.11.8)
ruby-progressbar (1.8.1, 1.7.5)
ruby2ruby (2.2.0)
ruby_parser (3.8.2, 3.7.3, 3.7.1)
rubycritic (2.9.4, 2.9.3, 2.7.1, 1.4.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.2.0, 1.1.7)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
s3_direct_upload (0.1.7)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sass (3.4.22, 3.4.21, 3.4.19, 3.4.18, 3.4.14, 3.2.19)
sass-rails (5.0.6, 5.0.4, 5.0.3, 4.0.5)
sdoc (0.4.1)
sexp_processor (4.7.0, 4.6.1, 4.6.0)
simple_calendar (2.1.0)
simple_form (3.3.1, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.0)
simple_oauth (0.3.1)
sinatra (1.4.6)
sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.1.1)
slim (3.0.6)
spoon (0.0.4)
spreadsheet (1.1.3, 1.1.1, 1.0.7, 1.0.3, 0.9.0)
spring (1.7.2, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.4.0, 1.3.6)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
sprockets (3.7.0, 3.6.3, 3.5.2, 3.4.0, 3.3.5, 3.3.4, 3.2.0, 2.12.4)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0, 3.0.4, 3.0.1, 2.3.3, 2.3.1, 2.0.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
streamio-ffmpeg (3.0.0, 1.0.0)
stripe (1.55.0, 1.54.0, 1.31.0)
sunspot (2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.0, 2.1.0)
sunspot_rails (2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.0, 2.1.0)
sunspot_solr (2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.0, 2.1.0)
temple (0.7.6)
terminal-notifier (1.6.3)
terminal-table (1.5.2)
therubyracer (0.12.2)
thin (1.6.4, 1.6.3)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
tilt (2.0.5, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 1.4.1)
timezone (0.99.2)
traceroute (0.5.0)
treetop (1.4.15)
trollop (2.1.2)
turbolinks (5.0.1, 2.5.3)
turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
twilio-ruby (4.6.1)
twitter (5.16.0, 5.15.0, 5.14.0)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.0)
twitter_oauth (0.4.94)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.44, 0.3.39)
uglifier (3.0.2, 3.0.0, 2.7.2, 2.7.1)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.2, 0.0.7.1)
unicode-display_width (1.1.1, 0.3.1)
unicorn (5.1.0, 5.0.1, 4.9.0, 4.1.1)
uniform_notifier (1.10.0, 1.9.0)
unparser (0.2.4)
virtus (1.0.5)
warden (1.2.6, 1.2.3)
web-console (3.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.1)
websocket-driver (0.6.4)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
whenever (0.9.4)
wicked_pdf (1.1.0, 1.0.3, 0.11.0)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.3, 0.9.9.3)
xml-simple (1.1.5)
```

Please help me to remove this `DEPRECATION WARNING`.

Comment: have you tried `gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'`?

Comment: Yes. But still same issue is there.

Comment: Are these the only two gems you're using? I've tried booting the server with `devise (4.2.0)` and `devise_token_auth (0.1.39)` and I'm not getting deprecation warnings. There aren't any `alias_method_chain` calls in the master version of [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alias_method_chain) and [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alias_method_chain).

Comment: Your Gemfile would be more helpful.

Comment: It has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem. They mention that this gem [is deprecated](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph#this-gem-is-deprecated), and you should use [fb_graph2](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph2). Unless you're using [deprecated](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph2/wiki/Deprecations) features, you should switch.

Replacing

```
gem 'fb_graph'
```

with

```
gem 'fb_graph2'
```

makes the deprecation warnings go away when you start the server.